# Image Position on an HTML/CSS Website

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML Document and a CSS Document and I'm trying to remove a large margin in between the image I've placed and the text below it. When I adjust the pixel margin on the top of the image it adjusts, but I've tried a few things on the bottom of the image and just can't seem to get it to work right. There is a huge gap and I just want it to look "normal". That is, having a smaller margin between the img and the text below it.

```html
<div id="header" class="container">
  <!--Home Logo -->
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://www.satckoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Stack-Overflow-Logo.png" style="position: relative; top: -150px;" alt="Platinum Imprints">
  </a>
  <p>Welcome! Here at Platinum Imprints we specialize in Custom Screen Printing. Use anywhere from one to many colors on a simple shirt.</p>
```

This is what I have for HTML.

Comment: Does the class container mean you're using bootstrap ?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO! To better help you please post your CSS code as well. Its most likely there is extra padding or margin in one of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have inline styles on the `img` element that are setting relative positioning. Removing this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline style `position: relative; top: -150px;` in the `img` tag to remove the spacing.